# Error using DBUtils in first scenario

Tags: karate

When I use DBUtils.java in Eclipse and run the tests there it works fine, but when I run it through Jenkins the first time that DBUtils are used is failing. And the second works...
The first time that it uses db.readRows it fails.

```
    Scenario: Account Create

    Given path 'accounts'
    And header Authorization = setup.authorization
    And request {identifier: KarateCreation, subscribers:[{identifier:KarateCreation, firstName:KarateCreation, lastName:KarateCreation}]}
    When method POST
    And match response contains { id: '#number', identifier: KarateCreation }
    Then status 201

    * def id = response.id
    * def accountNumber = response.identifier

    # use jdbc to validate
    * def config = { url: #(dbConnectionString), driverClassName: 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' }
    * def DbUtils = Java.type('restapi.util.DbUtils')
    * def db = new DbUtils(config)

    * def rs = db.readRows("SELECT ACCOUNTID, ACCOUNTNUMBER FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = 'KarateCreation'")
    * match rs contains { ACCOUNTID: '#(id)', ACCOUNTNUMBER: KarateCreation }
```

Error:

```
   * def rs = db.readRows("SELECT ACCOUNTID, ACCOUNTNUMBER FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = 'KarateCreation'")(Scenario: Account Create)  Time elapsed: 0.039 sec  <<< ERROR!
  java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: db.readRows("SELECT ACCOUNTID, ACCOUNTNUMBER FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = 'KarateCreation'")
at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.eval(ScriptBindings.java:115)
at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.updateBindingsAndEval(ScriptBindings.java:103)
at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.evalInNashorn(ScriptBindings.java:88)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalJsExpression(Script.java:362)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:284)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:170)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:598)
at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:524)
at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.def(StepDefs.java:305)
at ✽.* def rs = db.readRows("SELECT ACCOUNTID, ACCOUNTNUMBER FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = 'KarateCreation'")(restapi/accounts/accounts.feature:31)
  Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
```

Answer (score 1):

First may I gently remind you that `DBUtils.java` was created as a demo example and is not part of the core of Karate. I am beginning to regret having put this there because of questions like this. See [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51993446/143475).

EDIT - Since this question comes up a lot: **You are expected to write your own code to connect to your database, execute SQL and unpack the results the way you want. Please don't tag questions around this as "`karate`".**

Anyway, please work with somebody in your team or org to fix this problem:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: 
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
```

It is quite possible that your Jenkins box is not able to establish a connection to the database and the ports are fire-walled off etc.

Comment: Hi Peter. I'm not blaming DBUtil, because is working very well. What I don't know is why it is not able to connect in the first time using Jenkins.
First scenario it is shows that error, but works in the second on

Comment: @CarolCastro and I have tried to provide an answer. maybe someone else can provide a better one, but I doubt it.

Comment: I could fix doing it: Solution 2 - General Java JVM solution
Take a look at $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security
Change the line
securerandom.source=file:/dev/random
to
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110395/sqlrecoverableexception-i-o-exception-connection-reset