# Extract only the value and not the column name in SQL with karate dsl

Tags: javascript, java, cucumber, karate

I am using Karate for my test scenarios for the requirement to update the contract plan by passing the plan Id's and I am retrieving the planId from the database and passing it to my request json.

But the problem I am facing it comes with the column name whereas I only need the value.

Below is the example of how I am fetching my Id by connecting to the database

`@Scenario1
Scenario:

## use jdbc to validate

- def config = { username: 'mmultapp', password: 'Mmu1t@pp', url: 'jdbc:db2://edb2dev3.momentum.co.za:60022/MMULTTST', driverClassName: 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver' }
- def DbUtils = Java.type('wellness_core_utils.DbUtils')
- def db = new DbUtils(config)
- def productId = db.readRows('select PRODUCT_ID from MULTUSR1.PLANS  order by PLAN_ID desc fetch first 1 rows only')
- print productId`

And I am getting the results in this way

`{
    "PRODUCT_ID": 68
  }`

I only need to read the value of 68 so I that I can pass it to my json request

Thanks in advance

Comment: downvoting because no matter how many times I try to make this clear - this is not a Karate related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078427/143475

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query returns a key-value pair which you write in the query, Suppose you write

```
select PRODUCT_ID AS pId from MULTUSR1.PLANS order by PLAN_ID desc fetch first 1 rows only;
```

So It returns a `PRODUCT_ID` with the name `pId`. Later on, you can use that result as per your requirements

Let's try this in your instance.

```
def productId = db.readRows('select PRODUCT_ID from MULTUSR1.PLANS order by PLAN_ID desc fetch first 1 rows only').PRODUCT_ID;
const result =  productId.PRODUCT_ID;
```

> Notice: Please check the first type of your query result
>   Like It's in `[]` or `{}` 
>   In above instance I consider it in `{}`

```js
const result = [{ PRODUCT_ID: 87 }];
console.log(result[0].PRODUCT_ID);
```

Comment: Hi @Neel Rathod thanks for your reply, I just tried that but it doesn't solve the problem, it doesnt print anything

Comment: It always returns an object or an  array which holds your value along with keys

Comment: it is an array, this is how it comes

[
  {
    "PRODUCT_ID": 68
  }
]

Comment: Then you can access that property  by `array[index]`

Comment: In your instance, If you fetch only one entry then you can achieve it by ``` const result =  productId[0].PRODUCT_ID; ```