# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'YTLQVLBK' to data type int.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am calling a karate DButil to execute one of the database query in the karate script:

```
 * def test = db.readValue('SELECT * FROM CLIENT C WHERE C.ClientCode = ' + globalAccountID)
```

Here i', unable to convert the globalAccountID to string.
Please help on this.

My error trace is below:

> javascript evaluation failed: db.readRows('SELECT * FROM CLIENT C
>   WHERE C.ClientCode = ' + globalAccountID), StatementCallback;
>   uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT * FROM CLIENT C WHERE
>   C.ClientCode = 707]; SQL state [S0001]; error code [245]; Conversion
>   failed when converting the varchar value 'YTLQVLBK' to data type int.;
>   nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'YTLQVLBK' to data
>   type int.

Comment: please don't ask questions about databases with the karate tag, this is NOT related to Karate. please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078427/143475

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this code:

```
C.ClientCode = 707
```

More specifically, you are comparing an integer to a string. Based on SQL Server [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) rules, it means that column `C.ClientCode` is converted to integer before comparison can take place.

The solution is to convert `707` to string (varchar) type. You can do something like this:

```
'SELECT * FROM CLIENT C WHERE C.ClientCode = ''' + globalAccountID + ''''
```

Comment: A better solution would be to use a prepared statement with a parameter placeholder.