# Database proxy in karate

Tags: karate

I am using karate framework for my API testing in our organization. I am able to execute my project in **local where DB connections are successful**, when i execute in **cloud jenkins we are getting below error**

**Error** : **Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection**

DB class used: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/demo/util/DbUtils.java

Do we have any option to **set proxy for DB only**, i have also gone through proxy setup in karate-config.js like karate.configure('proxy', { uri: 'http://my.proxy.host:8080', username: 'john', password: 'secret' ,nonProxyHosts:['http://example.com'] }. This is setting up proxy to my API and not for DB instance.

I am also trying to check **whether my jenkins server firewall is blocking** to create a connection to my db.

Any help from karate framework creators or implementer's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whether my jenkins server firewall is blocking

That is most likely the case, nothing Karate (or anyone associated with it) can do here to help.

Also please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078427/143475

Comment: Thanks Peter Thomas for your immediate reply, will check with my organization.