# When i give postgres Db username and password from karateconfig.js getting authentication error

Tags: karate

When I give postgres Db username and password from karateconfig.js getting authentication error
var config = {
env: env,
db_username: karate.properties['karate.db_dev_username'], // username am passing from command
db_password: karate.properties['karate.db_dev_password'], // password am passing from command
}
calling in the feature file as below

```
* def username = db_username
* def password = db_password
* def config = { username: username, password: password, url: 'jdbc:postgresql://...', driverClassName: 'org.postgresql.Driver' }

* def DbUtils = Java.type('utilities.DbUtils')
* def db = new DbUtils(config)
```

if i give the username and password in the feature file directly, it working fine.

Comment: org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authent
ication failed for user "username"  - This is the error am getting

Comment: sorry, you have to sort this out in your local env: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078427/143475