# Execute a db stored procedure procedure in karate

Tags: database, karate

Is there a way I can execute a stored procedure from karate.

This is what I tried:

```
def StoredProc = db.runQuery(“EXEC spintegration.cleanup”)
```

The query executes correctly when I try it in the database. But in karate I am getting bad SQL grammar exception.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: this is completely dependent on how you implemented the `runQuery()` Java code and most likely has nothing to do with karate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078427/143475