# Using Karate, how can I query a DB that has 2 million records without running into java heap issue?

Tags: database, karate

I am getting java heap issue when I execute the below karate feature file using the gradle test command from terminal on my Mac. I used standard DbUtils class from karate framework. The testtable1 and testable2 are temporary tables in the database and each table has over 2 million records. I tried to add the gradle.properties with option = org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g and also appended the same in grade test command in CLI like this ./gradlew test -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx4g" when running the test case The test1 should return just 10 records. If we execute the same query in the database it takes around 38 seconds or so

```
@parallel=false
Feature: Perform DB validations

  Background: 
    * def DbUtils = Java.type('com.API.DbUtils')
    * def config = karate.call('classpath:karate-config.js')
    * def db = new DbUtils(config.db)


    @Dbvalidation
    Scenario: test DB
      * def test1 = db.readRows('select * from testtable1 except select * from testtable2;’)
      * print test1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `standard DbUtils class from karate framework`. What you are referring to is [just an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078427/143475), and you should write the Java code needed for your project.

So this is something you have to figure out for yourself.