# MySQL database insertion with karate

Tags: karate

In the karate project I am trying I have used karate's ability to assert database entries. And I was looking for a way to insert SQL scripts as a 'given' inside the test rather than calling a java class. Did not see any example in the demo project of karate.
What would be the ideal way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have already seen the [JDBC demo](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/dogs/dogs.feature) and still feel that is too complicated, then I'm sorry - look for another framework :)

Also see this example if it helps: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1144458169822806016

And the whole `Given` `When` `Then` approach is over-rated, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47799207/143475

Comment: I never mentioned that it's complicated. I just didn't find an example with sql insertion as a prerequisite and wanted to know if there's an ideal way of doing the insertion.

Comment: @NironRasanjanaPerera you said "rather than calling a java class" which is the same thing. anyway, lets assume I have no idea what you mean by "as a 'given'" and please assume that there is no better way. and by the way please stop the twitter reminders, there is no need

Comment: Sorry about that and I think you have misunderstood the question. I was not asking for a better way. In the demo project you have done database assertions within test. I was asking for a way to insert the data to the db like that.

Comment: @NironRasanjanaPerera think hard and then answer this question - do you really think what you are asking is a "Karate" question or a "SQL" question. and why don't  you do a search here for Karate and JDBC and see what you find: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51996544/143475

Comment: I did not see this question and seems like it is the same question I have. Anyway thanks I will work on it.